# Web worker is showing error and I have no idea why

Tags: web-worker

**IMPORTANT:** Due to requirements, all my HTML files has to be loaded using the file protocol `file://` (open the HTML file in the browser by clicking on it / drag drop onto a browser).

Due to the usage of web workers from the file protocol & unable to modify anything on the browser, I am currently running the codes in Firefox.

---

My file structure is as follow:

```
main
 |-index.html
 |-pages
 |  |-module1
 |       |-page1.html
 |-js
 |  |-index.js
 |-deps
    |-worker.js
```

`index.js` is loaded into `page1.html`:

`<script src="../../js/index.js"></script>`

`index.js` is trying to load the webworker file `worker.js`:

```
const workerURL = '../../deps/worker.js';

let worker = new Worker(workerURL);

worker.onmessage = (evnt) => {
   console.log('success!');
}

worker.onerror = (evnt) => {
   console.log('error: ',evnt.message);
}

worker.postMessage('');
```

The result of running the above is `error!`. Even if I were to run it with the `workerURL = deps/worker.js`, the same error happens. Whats most frustrating is that under `worker.onerror`'s console.log shows `error: undefined`.

I have been stuck here for a long time and have no idea how to resolve this. I don't even know how to debug what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue. I opened my application in Firefox as opposed to Chrome, and I saw an error in the console: "The resource was blocked due to MIME type ('text/html') mismatch" regarding my web worker script passed into the Worker constructor. Do you think you might have the same issue? Specifically serve the script as application/javascript type or provide a url into the constructor that strictly serves a js file, since browers won't load resources with a mismatched content type. Here's some additional information: https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-mime-sniffing

Comment: Mine is on a file protocol. Means no server is serving the file. Hm